# Android Realm version upgrade error with gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, realm, build.gradle

We are developing an android application together with an SDK. The SDK is a module for the app. We are using Realm only in the SDK (for now). The only gradle file I've added something about Realm is the sdk build.gradle file. I've added the **apply plugin: 'realm-android'** on the top of the file and

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.90.1"
    } 
}
```

on the bottom of the file. Everything was compiling and working correctly until we tried to upgrade to the latest version (1.1.0).

If I change the version to 1.0.0 or later, it doesn't compile. Here some error logs:
Gradle console:

```
Note: Processing class TransactionUpdateAPICall
Note: Processing class Address
Note: Creating DefaultRealmModule
PersistentDataManager.java:134: error: no suitable method found for    findAllSorted(String,Sort,String,Sort,String,Sort)
            objects = query.findAllSorted(sorts.get(0).fieldName,sorts.get(0).dir,sorts.get(1).fieldName,sorts.get(1).dir,sorts.get(2).fieldName,sorts.get(2).dir);
                           ^
method RealmQuery.findAllSorted(String,Sort) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method RealmQuery.findAllSorted(String) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method RealmQuery.findAllSorted(String[],Sort[]) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method RealmQuery.findAllSorted(String,Sort,String,Sort) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

The Messages window displays also some error messages from the Gradle build:

```
Error:(134, 32) error: no suitable method found for          findAllSorted(String,Sort,String,Sort,String,Sort)
method RealmQuery.findAllSorted(String,Sort) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method RealmQuery.findAllSorted(String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method RealmQuery.findAllSorted(String[],Sort[]) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method RealmQuery.findAllSorted(String,Sort,String,Sort) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
Error:Execution failed for task ':sdk:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.*
```

If I create sample app and add Realm (last version) into the app gradle build file, it works. The issue is with the Realm used into the SDK module.

If you already had some similar issues and resolved them, or have an idea what is wrong, please share it. It would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

The fix was that I had to comment all the used deprecated methods, and then to compile. The compiler was showing all Realm objects as missing. Once the deprecated methods were commented out, the build succeeded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Realm-Java Changelog](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

- 0.90.0

Deprecated

`Realm.allObjects*()`. Use `Realm.where(clazz).findAll*()` instead.

`Realm.distinct*()`. Use `Realm.where(clazz).distinct*()` instead.

`DynamicRealm.allObjects*()`. Use `DynamicRealm.where(className).findAll*()` instead.

`DynamicRealm.distinct*()`. Use `DynamicRealm.where(className).distinct*()` instead.

**`Realm.allObjectsSorted(field, sort, field, sort, field, sort)`. Use `RealmQuery.findAllSorted(field[], sort[])` instead.**

> **`RealmQuery.findAllSorted(field, sort, field, sort, field, sort)`. Use `RealmQuery.findAllSorted(field[], sort[])` instead.**

**`RealmQuery.findAllSortedAsync(field, sort, field, sort, field, sort)`. Use `RealmQuery.findAllSortedAsync(field[], sort[])` instead.**

`RealmConfiguration.setModules()`. Use `RealmConfiguration.modules()` instead.

`Realm.refresh()` and `DynamicRealm.refresh()`. Use `Realm.waitForChange()`/`stopWaitForChange()` or `DynamicRealm.waitForChange()`/`stopWaitForChange()` instead.

- 0.91.0

Breaking changes: Removed all @Deprecated methods.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The problem is that it doesn't allows me to use the basic Realm classes (io.realm.Ream, RealmObject etc.) They don't exist, so all my code related to Realm can't be compiled.

Comment: I marked your cause of the issue in yellow. However, you're supposed to be able to use `RealmObject` and the like, as long as the library provides its schema exposed through a RealmModule.

Comment: I guess the issue is with Gradle and the building process itself. I had to comment all the places there is something deprecated, and then it compiled successfully. The compiler didn't show just the missing deprecated classes and functions, but pretty much all Realm classes.

Comment: Ah, then it's a question of clean/rebuild

Answer (score 10):

The main upgrade to Realm from `olds verson` to `5+` needs to change from:

```
realm.where(example.class)
    .findAllSorted("field")
```

To:

```
realm.where(example.class)
    .sort("field")
    .findAll();
```

Comment: How do we include `distinct` on the same results? it is throwing [error](https://ibb.co/thN91TG) on distinct after the latest update.

Comment: `realm.where(example.class)
    .sort("field", Sort.DESCENDING)
    .findAll();`

Comment: Distinct is still not added in your answer.